# Travelling to Taiwan in September/October

Tags: weather-and-climate, seasonal, taiwan

I would like to travel to Taiwan in late September-late October. June to October [seems](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/climate/taipei.htm) to be the typhoon season. I plan to stay around Taipei City and will mostly be a food tourist—so no windsurfing or climbing mountains.

Is the typhoon season very bad during this time? Would October be a lot better in terms of less rain and wind, or is late September still OK?

Comment: You should care about the weather forecast. Typhoons almost don't hit Taiwan in October.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Typhoons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoon) are the Pacific equivalent of hurricanes, great big storms that only hit occasionally, almost always in the August-October typhoon season, and Taiwan gets an average of 3-4 per year.  If a typhoon hits squarely where you happen to be staying, you can expect to be washed out for a couple of days, possibly even briefly stranded if you're out in the countryside if there are landslides that take out roads and railways.

However, between the typhoons (which is 95% of the time), you'll be absolutely fine, with clear fall skies and the occasional random sprinkle.  Here's a rainfall chart:

[image]

As you can see, outside the sparsely populated east coast (=Hualien), it rains a lot more in the summer than it does in either of Sep or Oct.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, for some reason I thought they were very frequent.

Comment: @row1 You should also be aware of the number of tropical storms. They are frequent. Generally, there are between 25-30 tropical storms/typhoons per year! You should be fine in Taipei, but you can use one of the many foriegner website for more information. Tealit is the one I use: http://www.tealit.com/article_categories.php?section=weather&article=typhoon

Answer (score 4):

In all probability you'll be fine. Unless you are getting a direct hit from the eye of the typhoon, you'll only experience a day or two of heavy rain and some wind. If your in a big city and shopping/dinning, you wont notice much. If you do find yourself on course for a hit, Taiwan is big enough that you could move to another city and keep out of the way. Just keep an eye on the weather forecasts.